# Intersections of a Line and Plane in 3-Space

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Given the line $(x, y, z) = (1, -3, 2) + t(-2, 4, 7)$, find planes to satisfy the following conditions:

- A plane which is intersected by the line at the point $(3, -7, -5)$,
- A plane which is not intersected by the line,
- A plane that the line lies on.

The course content doesn't cover this specifically so I have no clue how to approach answering it.

Comment: Do you at least know how to construct the equation of a plane given a point and normal?

Comment: Yes, we learned how to do that.

Comment: Well, then you *do* have a clue. For instance, you might use the direction of the line as the normal to the first plane.

Answer (score 0):

I'll get you started and then you try to finish it. This will give a plane NOT intersected by the line.

To find a vector that is perpendicular to your line, form the dot product of the line's direction vector and this unknown orthogonal vector. Like this:

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}-2\\4\\7\end{array}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\\z\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\0\end{array}\right)$$

Next, pick two values for $x$ and $y$.  It doesn't matter, but I like to pick $x=4$ and $y=2$. (reverse x & y and change the sign of one of them). $$\left(\begin{array}{c}-2\\4\\7\end{array}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c}4\\2\\z\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\0\end{array}\right)$$
Now solve for z. You can pretty much see by inspection that z will be 0.  Thus an orthogonal vector to the line is (4,2,0).   Now pick a point that is not on the line. Let's call it P and you figure out what coordinates it has.  A plane that is parallel to the line and passes through point P will be $$\left(\begin{array}{c}4\\2\\0\end{array}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\\z\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}4\\2\\0\end{array}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c}P_{x}\\P_{y}\\P_{z}\end{array}\right)$$ By & by, it is totally possible to pick a P that is not on your line, but still causes this plane to pass through your line, so be careful.